# Django API REST error using Postman: "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: django

EDIT

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying authtoken.0001_initial... OK
  Applying authtoken.0002_auto_20160226_1747... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv       
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db 
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

---

I learn about Django API REST and have implemented the quickstart project (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/).
It works fine locally but I would like to use API with Postman but it dose'nt works

I got 401 Unauthorized error
I try adding 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' key in settings.py but dose'nt works neither

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

moreover, I have a huge traceback in terminal when saving projects (below), even if py manage.py runserver works

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 334, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db 
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
[02/Sep/2020 16:34:13] "GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57191)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 334, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db 
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request 
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error       
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 381, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 287, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 357, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
----------------------------------------
D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\api_django\tutorial\settings.py changed, reloading.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv       
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle 
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run   
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader       
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 355, in tick
    self.notify_file_changed(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 330, in notify_file_changed     
    trigger_reload(path)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 218, in trigger_reload
    sys.exit(3)
SystemExit: 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv       
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db 
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle 
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run   
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 601, in run_with_reloader       
    sys.exit(exit_code)
SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv       
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db 
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\jl3.PRT-063\Desktop\Python\Django\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are going to have to create a token for the user you are trying to log in as.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

token = Token.objects.create(user=...)
print(token.key)
```

Then you want to include that token in your url head

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Here is some documentation look under TokenAuthentication.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

In post man you can just click the header box and type in your token there. This should authenticate you, you just have to generate the token for your user first.

Here is a link to some documentation on how to work with common authentication types with postman. https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: ok, it works. Don't know why it was not precise in the tutorial...

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: hope this helps.
ps: can you mark the question as solved/ upvote the answer